# Missing data in a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am creating a dataframe name "salesdata" and it has a column name "Outlet_Size",this column contains some missing data.This is my code-:

```
#defining a dictionary
cat_dict ={}
#getting all the values of the column
outlet_size_values = salesdata.Outlet_Size.values
unique_outlet_size_val = list(set(outlet_size_values))  
print(unique_outlet_size_val)
```

the output I am getting is
    [nan,'High','Medium','Small']
I don't want this missing data(nan) to be the part of my list and I don;t want to create a new list for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use basic pandas functions: `dropna` to remove the nan values, then `unique` to get the set-equivalent result:

```
salesdata.Outlet_Size.dropna().unique()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` has the function [unique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get distinct values. You can use this and filter out NaNs like

```
salesdata.loc[~salesdata.Outlet_Size.isnull(), 'Outlet_Size'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.unique`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.unique(salesdata.Outlet_Size.dropna().values)
```